# grouping result from multiple queries and aggregating result mongo

Tags: mongodb

I'm new to mongo and I have a document that has an array with the ids of all it's related documents. I need to fetch the document with all it's relateds in a single query. For the moment I fetch the document and I query separatly each of it's related document with there ids.

all my documents are on the same collection `documents_nodes` and look like so:

```
{
  "id": "document_1",
  "name": "flask",
  "relateds": [
     "document_2",
     "document_3",
     "document_4"
  ],
  "parents": [
     "document1_1"
  ]
}
```

The first query is to get the initial document

```
db.documents_nodes.find({id: document_1})
```

And then I query it's relateds with a second query

```
db.documents_nodes.aggregate([{
$match: {
    $and: [{
        id: {
            $in: ["document_2", "document_3", "document_2"]
        }
    }]
 }
}])
```

is there a way to combine the two queries, I tried this but it doesn't work

```
db.documents_nodes.aggregate([
 {
   $match: {

        uri: "https://opus.adeo.com/LMFR_prod/3206"

  }
},
{
  $addFields: { 
    newRelateds:
     { 
       $match: {

         id: {
               $in: [ "$relateds" ]  
         }
       }
     } 
   }
 }
])
```

> "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$match'",
>     "code" : 168,
>       "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-multiple-joins

Comment: Great, tkx @AnthonyWinzlet I'll try the aggregation to build my query

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I have edited my question with I've found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do it, in case someone has the same need.

I used the `$unwind` to flatten the array of documents and then used the `$lookup` to fetch the documents by their ids and finally I group the result on a new key.

```
[{
   $match: {
    id: "document_1"
   }
 }, {
   $unwind: {
    path: '$relateds',
   }
 }, {
   $lookup: {
    from: 'documents_nodes',
    localField: 'relateds',
    foreignField: 'id',
    as: 'newRelateds'
    }
 }, {
   $group: {
    _id: '$id',
    relateds: {
        '$push': '$newRelateds'
     }
   }
}]
```